# Reseting select box based on value of other selectbox

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have multiple select boxes, say: ID, RollNo, Name and class.

If ID is set ,I want to reset the RollNo, name and class to nothing or blank.

My web page

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('id', 
                              array("options"=>$databaseFields->getOptions("id",1))); ?> 
<?php echo $this->Form->input('RollNo', 
                              array("options"=>$databaseFields->getOptions("rollno",1))); ?> 
<?php echo $this->Form->input('name', 
                              array("options"=>$databaseFields->getOptions("name",1))); ?> 
<?php echo $this->Form->input('class', 
                              array("options"=>$databaseFields->getOptions("class",1))); ?>
```

Comment: exactly, paste the complete code for the page..

Comment: <?php echo $this->Form->input('id', array("options"=>$databaseFields->getOptions("id",1))); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('RollNo', array("options"=>$databaseFields->getOptions("rollno",1))); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('name', array("options"=>$databaseFields->getOptions("name",1))); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('class', array("options"=>$databaseFields->getOptions("class",1))); ?>

Comment: I am using php so above is what I am doing. where the select box gets data from DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this easily using jQuery. Since we don't have much information about your HTML I present a more generalized solution.

Add the following to your `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

(or download the .js file and point to it's local path)

Then add something along these lines also on the `<head>` of your document:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#selectID").change(function()
  {
      //Reset any select boxes
      $("#selectOther")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
  });
});
```

You can see a working example at http://jsfiddle.net/zPhnN/1/

This should be modified to suit your needs, but hopefully it's something to get you started.